# Проблема с вложенными шаблонами

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Допустим, имеется некоторый класс:

```
class Base
{
public:
    INLINE static int get_something()
    {
        return 777;
    }
    
    //....
};
```

А также объявлен следующий шаблонный класс A:

```
template <class TBase>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename TObject>
    INLINE static TObject get_something()
    {
        return (TObject)(TBase::get_something() + 1);
    }

    //....
};
```

Теперь мы можем использовать это в коде, например так:

```
double a = A<Base>::get_something<double>();
printf("A: %lf\n", a);
```

Отлично, всё работает! Однако добавим теперь шаблонный класс B, который можно рассматривать, как некоторую оболочку над A:

```
template <class TBase>
class B
{
public:
    template <typename TObject>
    INLINE static TObject get_something()
    {
        return (TObject)(A<TBase>::get_something<TObject>() + 1); //Тут компилятор ругается!
    }

    //....
};
```

И с ходу получаем от компилятора:

```
main.cpp: In static member function 'static TObject B<TBase>::get_something()':
main.cpp:38:57: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   38 |         return (TObject)(A<TBase>::get_something<TObject>() + 1);
      |                                                         ^
main.cpp:38:59: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   38 |         return (TObject)(A<TBase>::get_something<TObject>() + 1);
```

При этом, если в выражении `A<TBase>::get_something<TObject>()` заменить шаблонный параметр `TBase` на явный тип `Base`, то всё снова работает:

```
template <class TBase>
class B
{
public:
    template <typename TObject>
    INLINE static TObject get_something()
    {
        return (TObject)(A<Base>::get_something<TObject>() + 1); //А тут всё хорошо...
    }

    //....
};

//...и мы можем это использовать в коде
float b = B<Base>::get_something<float>();
printf("B: %f\n", b);
```

Вопрос, что не нравится компилятору и как заставить его корректно разыменовывать параметр шаблона класса A, функция которого вызывается из шаблонной функции шаблонного класса B? Вот, как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запишите так:

```
return (TObject)(A<TBase>::template get_something<TObject>() + 1);
```

Comment: Класс, всё работает! А я, дубина, какие только варианты не перепробовал...)))

Comment: VC++ поясняет куда более понятно, и дает совет по исправлению: *error C7510: "get_something": при использовании зависимого имени шаблон необходимо указать префикс "шаблон"*. Суть-то одна и та же, надо пояснить, что `get_something<TObject>` — шаблон, а не "`get_something` меньше `TObject`", на что ругается ваш компилятор.

Comment: а, вон оно в чём дело! А ведь действительно двусмысленность получается: т.к. класс `A<TBase>`  заранее неизвестен, то и тип идентификатора `get_something` тоже. И получается, что  GCC по умолчанию считает его переменной, а не шаблоном функции. Как всё бывает неочевидно, однако...